# Formula for calculating max winning seasons in a sports league?

Tags: statistics, logic

A co-worker and I had a friendly disagreement about whether all teams in a sports league can have a winning season during the same season. I don't think that is statistically possible, but I got wondering what the formula would be for calculating the *maximum percentage of teams that can have a winning season in any given year*.

Here are the premises:

- There are an even number of teams. For example, there are 130 collegiate division 1 football teams in the United States.
- For each game, 1 team wins and 1 team loses. There are no ties because of overtime play.
- The definition of a winning season is winning **more** games than you lose. For the case in which a team plays 12 games, wins 6 and loses 6, that is *not* a winning season. Technically it's not a losing season either, but it's not a winning season, and thus cannot be counted in the "winning season" bucket.
- Each team plays roughly the same amount of games. In college football a typical season is 12 games, not counting playoffs/bowls.

So the essential question is, *what is the most number of teams out of 130 (or any number) that can have a winning season within a given league/season?* A secondary question is, *is there an elegant formula to describe the maximum possible number of teams with winning seasons within a given league/season?*

Comment: It depends on who each team plays. If 129 teams only play the 130th team, then we could have 129 teams with a winning season.

Comment: No, because each team plays roughly the same amount of games. I'll update my original post to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general solution, let there be $N$ teams in the league,
and each team plays exactly $G$ games.
If we were to give a token to each team each time it played a game,
we would give out $NG$ tokens over the course of a season.
But we give out exactly two tokens for each game, one to each of the
teams that played in that game.
Therefore the total number of games played in the league,
which is equal to the total number of wins (summed over all teams),
is $NG/2.$

Notice that it is impossible to have an odd number of teams in the league and have each team play an odd number of games.
At least one of the numbers $N$ or $G$ must be even.

Consider the case where each team plays an even number of games.
That is, assume $G = 2k$ for some positive integer $k.$
Then the total number of wins, summed over all teams, is $N(2k)/2 = Nk.$

But in order to have a winning season, a team must have $k+1$ wins.
In order to maximize the number of teams with winning seasons, we give each team just that many wins, for as many teams as we can.
The number of teams we can do this for is just
$$
w_0 = \left\lfloor \frac{Nk}{k+1} \right\rfloor
 = \left\lfloor \frac{NG}{2(k+1)} \right\rfloor
 = \left\lfloor \frac{NG}{G + 2} \right\rfloor
$$
(that is, divide $NG$ by $G + 2,$ and if the result is not an integer,
round down.)

In the case where each team plays an odd number of games,
let each team play $2k+1$ games.
Then the total number of games played is $N(2k+1)/2.$
It still takes $k+1$ wins to have a winning season, so the maximum number
of winning teams is
$$
w_1 = \left\lfloor \frac{N(2k+1)/2}{k+1} \right\rfloor
= \left\lfloor \frac{NG}{2(k+1)} \right\rfloor
= \left\lfloor \frac{NG}{G + 1} \right\rfloor.
$$

We can combine the
two formulas together as follows:
$$
w = \begin{cases}
\left\lfloor \dfrac{NG}{G+2} \right\rfloor & \text{if $G$ is even,} \\[0.5ex]
\left\lfloor \dfrac{NG}{G+1} \right\rfloor & \text{if $G$ is odd.}
\end{cases}
$$

This combined formula is good in every possible case: an even number of teams
playing any number of games or an odd number of teams playing an even number of games.

Example: A league has $130$ teams and each plays in $12$ games.
Then $N = 130$ and $G=12$; since $G$ is even, the maximum possible number of winning teams is
$$
\left\lfloor \dfrac{130\times12}{12+2} \right\rfloor
=\left\lfloor \dfrac{1560}{14} \right\rfloor
= 111.
$$
One way for this to happen is that $111$ teams each win exactly $7$ games,
one team wins $3$ games, and the other $18$ teams lose every game.
We then have a total of $111\times7 + 3 = 777 + 3 = 780$ wins
and $111\times5 + 9 + 18\times12 = 555 + 9 + 216 = 780$ losses,
one winner and one loser in each of the
$780$ games played by the entire league.

Comment: David this looks very promising, but could you assign constants to a few of the variables, for clarity? Going back to my 130-team example, I'm unclear whether 2n = 130 or n = 130. Also I'm unclear what k represents exactly. g is clear. So if you could tell (for the 130-team example with 12 games per team) what number is n and what number is k, that would be outstanding. Thank you.

Comment: I have made some changes. My answer (as I first posted it) was _wrong,_ so I have corrected it; I don't really need the assumption that the number of teams is even, so I have just assumed $N$ teams instead of $2n$ teams (which I think will be easier for you to work with); and I have worked out your $130$-team example in detail.

Comment: Nicely done David! So I see that, at least with the example presented, approximately 85% of all teams, at most, could have a winning season. Excellent! Thank you.